# Issue with scheduling in Linux

Tags: bash, shell, at-job

I scheduled a script using `at` scheduler in linux.

The job ran fine but the echo statements which I had redirected to a file are no where to be found.

The at scheduling command is as follows:

```
at -f /app/data/scripts/func_test.sh >> /app/data/log/log.txt 2>&1 -v 09:50
```

Can anyone point out what is the issue with the above command.

I cannot see any echo statements from the script in the log.txt file

Comment: Does the the user you scheduled the job with have permission to write to the `/app/data/log/log.txt` file?

Comment: Yes the log.txt is also created by the same user.

Comment: At puts output from a job to result email. If you want to get output into a file, you should place output redirection to the script itself, in this case func_test.sh.

Comment: @Sami Laine: Can you show the syntax of how that should be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To include shell syntax like I/O redirection, you'll need to either fold it into your script, or pass the input to `at` via standard input, like so:

```
at -v 09:50 <<EOF
sh /app/data/scripts/func_test.sh >> /app/data/log/log.txt 2>&1
EOF
```

If `func_test.sh` is already executable, you can omit the `sh` from the beginning of the command; it's there to ensure that you are passing a valid command line to `at`.

You can also simply ensure that your script itself redirects all its output to a specific log file. As an example,

```
#!/bin/bash

echo foo
echo bar
```

becomes

```
#!/bin/bash

{ 
echo foo
echo bar
} >> /app/data/log/log.txt 2>&1
```

Then you can simply run your script with `at` using

```
at -f /app/data/scripts/func_test.sh -v 09:50
```

with no output redirection, because the script itself already redirects all its output to that file.

Comment: Worked perfectly, what is the other syntax of folding into one's script.